# Appropriateness of a Django Textfield in a Model

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I have a field in a model that I want users to feel like they can write an arbitrary amount of text in. Django provides a CharField and a TextField in the models. I assume that the difference is that one of them is a char(max_length) and the other is a varchar internally.

I am tempted to use the TextField, but since it doesn't respect max_length, I am somewhat wary of someone dumping loads of data into it and DOSing my server. How should I deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fields in model only represent the way data is stored in database.

You can very easily enforce maximum length in form which will validate users' input. Like this.

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=16384, widget=forms.TextArea)
    ...
```

This will make sure the maximum length user can successfully enter is 16k.

Comment: Too bad, I wish I could just use ModelForm without modifying the representation. I like keeping magic numbers all in one place :-)

Comment: Actually, you can still use ModelForm and just customize it for that field. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types

Comment: It should say widget=forms.Textarea instead of forms.TextArea.